# Cannot Autowire interface in spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am developing a REST API using spring boot. Following is my package structure
Getting the following exception when I try to start my application

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field articleRepository in com.abc.service.ArticleService required a bean of type 'com.abc.dao.ArticleRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.abc.dao.ArticleRepository' in your configuration.
```

Following is my project structure-

```
com.abc
com.abc.bean
    -Article.java
com.abc.controller
    -ArticleController.java
com.abc.dao
    -ArticleRepository.java (Interface)
com.abc.service
    -ArticleService.java
com.abc.web
    -AbcApplication.java (main Springboot class)
```

In AbcApplication.java as it is not in the root package, I have the below annotations

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.abc.*")
```

I tried few ways -

- I moved AbcApplication.java to root package com.abc but no success
- Instead of interface(ArticleRepository.java) I made it a class, **it is working**
- I keep it as interface but changed annotation from @Repository to @Service/Component still no success.

I am confused how it is working if I change it to class instead of interface.

```
@Repository
public interface ArticleRepository {

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to use Spring Data to autogenerate the repository? If so, you haven't shown any of that configuration. If not, do you *have* any implementation of it?

Comment: Add`@EntityScan( basePackages = {"com.abc.*"} )` in your main class

Comment: @chrylis Yes. I needed to add a implementation for it.

Comment: Try adding `extends Repository<Article, ID>` where `ID` is the type of the identifier of the `Article`.

Comment: Put your `AbcApplication` in the `com.abc` package and restart. Else it will only detect and auto configure stuff in the `com.abc.web` and sub packages. However your repository etc. isn't in that package. With that you can also remove the `@ComponentScan`. Also your `ArticleRepository` assuming you want to use Spring Data, needs to extend `CrudRepository` (or `Repository` at least to get detected).

Answer (score 3):

You don't have any bean for ArticleRepository. If you will use Spring Data Jpa you have to extend a type of Repository: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.

If you will use your own repository, you must implement it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using any RDBMS and if `ArticleRepository` repository is responsible for interacting with your database, then you need to either extends `CrudRepository` or `JpaRepository` in your `ArticleRepository`, then only Spring will be able to create the bean of `ArticleRepository`,and you will be able to autowire your repository.

If you are not extending any of `CrudRepository` or `JpaRepository`,then at the time of bean creation,`ArticleRepository` is only plain java interface and a plain interface can not be instantiated.

And as for your question:

```
Instead of interface(ArticleRepository.java) I made it a class, it is working
```

Its because when you declare it as a class, then Spring does instantiate a concrete class, so actual object will be created at the bean creation time and everything will be working as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should have one class that implements interface ArticleRepository . Annotate that class with @Repository, spring will take care of wiring.

Comment: Yes. If I add implementation for interface, it works. Thanks

Comment: Spring Data can "autoimplement" repositories with an interface only. Implementation is not absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I was also encountered with the same issue. What I missed was the **spring-boot-starter-jpa** dependency. It worked when I added this dependency in the pom.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

MyBatis gives you two samples to access your databases with spring boot.@ Component or @Mapper.

Sample link:
[mybatis-spring-boot-sample-xml](https://github.com/mybatis/spring-boot-starter/tree/master/mybatis-spring-boot-samples/mybatis-spring-boot-sample-xml)

Suggestion:
Show your **ArticleRepository** code fully.

Answer (score 0):

interface does not require any annotation (neither @repository not @Service).

If its a DAO file add @Repository annotation to the class implementing the corresponding interface.

And, if its a service then add @Service annotation to the class implementing the corresponding interface.